# How to appropriately respond when a query fails in a webapp?

Tags: php, sql, web-applications, error-handling, user-experience

Half of the [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.php) functions return false on failure. For trouble shooting when developing this is great, but when released how and should this be used? For example if a user encounters an error the technical info may not be relevant so should everything like it be removed from the final product? Part of me is afraid that if the script where the problem happened is included by another script, that would confuse people and would mess up scalability.

```
if(!$link)
    die('Can\'t connect to MySQL: '.mysql_error());
$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($link, 'Storage1');
if(!$db_selected)
    die('Can\'t use Storage1: '.mysql_error());
```

Comment: You should be very careful about what you show the user. Log the error so you can use it in debugging, but never output it to the user. The less they know the better.

Comment: Normal practice is to use try catch statement which can be applied from low level class till ui display along with logs so at top level user friendly error message can be get displayed while actual error goes to log using which developer can rectify for further prevention

Answer (score 1):

You should never show these messages to the visitor / user.

Instead you should log the error on the server and display a friendly message to the user to try again / try again later / apologize / etc.